# Laravel Jetstream with Intertia not returning User

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have installed Jetstream with Intertia.  I register a user, then try to login, and the console gives me the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$page.user is null"
```

When I look at the response from the controller, indeed it does not include a user.

Where is the user attached?  Presumably in some middleware.  But which?

Here are two web routes that exhibit the problem.  Note the differences in middleware.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia\Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/map', [MapController::class, 'show'])->name('map');
```

I have also tried the middleware `auth:sanctum` and `verified`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about the user. It's attached in the `ShareInertiaData` middleware provided by Jestream.

Assuming you updated inertia to some newer version, the reason why your user is `null` has probably something to do with the fact that since `inertia-vue@v0.3.0` the `$page` returns a full page object, instead of just the page props - so in your case, instead of `$page.user`, you'd have to go with `$page.props.user`.

https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/releases/tag/inertia-vue%40v0.3.0